# ActiveRecord Transaction and return the saved id of the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, translation

I want to use ActiveRecord transactions to save three of my models. I was able to find some good tutorials like

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html

http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html

But my question is, I want to get my first model's id and save it as a foreign key with my second model. As far as I know I couldn't do this because I cannot get the saved id until the transaction commits.

Does anyone have a better solution or workaround for this problem? I'm using Rails 2.3.8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about:

```
SomeClass.transaction do
  first_record = SomeClass.create(... vars ...)
  second_record = SomeClass.create(... vars ...)
  third_record = SomeClass.create(... vars ...)

  second_record.update_attributes(:related_id=>first_record.id)
  third_record.update_attributes(:related_id=>second_record.id)
end
```

That would create the objects, and assign the ids in one overall transaction. If it fails, all records should be rolled back, including the creation of the records in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

Generally when you need to save objects with relationships, it means you should use `accepts_nested_attributes_for`. [See doc here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html).

It's by far the cleanest and the best way to proceed.